# Unable to create tables automatically in Orcale11xe database using spring mvc, Spring Orm and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-orm

My code

Emp.java (Entity)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Emp")
public class Emp {

    @Id
    private int eno;
    private String ename;
    private int sal;

    public Emp() {
        super();
    }
 // followed by getter and setters
```

Bean Creation of datasource and sessionFatory

```
@Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException{
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        cpds.setUser("spring3");
        cpds.setPassword("spring3");
        return cpds;
    }

    //Bean for sessionFactory.
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sf.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sf.setPackagesToScan("com.wp");
        sf.setAnnotatedClasses(Emp.class);
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        p.setProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        p.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        sf.setHibernateProperties(p);
        return sf;
    }
```

When I try to add an employee to my database then throws an exception that is:

> "Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement"

```
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    com.wp.dao.EmployeeDaoImplementation.insertEmp(EmployeeDaoImplementation.java:28)
    com.wp.services.EmployeeService.save(EmployeeService.java:28)
    com.wp.controllers.EmployeeController.employeeEntry(EmployeeController.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    com.wp.dao.EmployeeDaoImplementation.insertEmp(EmployeeDaoImplementation.java:28)
    com.wp.services.EmployeeService.save(EmployeeService.java:28)
    com.wp.controllers.EmployeeController.employeeEntry(EmployeeController.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1449)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    com.wp.dao.EmployeeDaoImplementation.insertEmp(EmployeeDaoImplementation.java:28)
    com.wp.services.EmployeeService.save(EmployeeService.java:28)
    com.wp.controllers.EmployeeController.employeeEntry(EmployeeController.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

My Pom.xml dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wp</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringSecond</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <name>SpringSecond Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.20.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringSecond</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you checked whether the code you want to be executed on the DB can run? Have you investigated this part of the exception? `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: Yes, I have been provided priviledges to my database user to create and delete tables from databse. And This configuration file does create any table that's why it is unable to find table in database.

Comment: Yes I have investigated much about this exception but found nothing.